# Firebase on disconnect callback

Tags: android, firebase

Is it possible to add a callback method in Firebase on Disconnect that I can used for to perform some operation rather than Firebase while the user goes offline

```
.onDisconnect().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
```

It is possible to update value in firebase while onDisconnect is called  is it possible call a user defined method on this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **is** possible to update a value in the Firebase database when the user disconnects. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-presence

But since these `onDisconnect()` handlers run on the Firebase servers, it is **not** possible to call user-defined functions. If you want to run some code in your Android app when it detects that it has lost its connection to the Firebase servers, you can run a presence system: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-connection-state

Answer (score 1):

this works for me!

```
DBManager.mOnlineRef.child(currentUserID).setValue(currentUserEmail);
DBManager.mOnlineRef.child(currentUserID).onDisconnect().removeValue(new  DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Should be removed");
            }
});
```